# Shell script if elif usage need suggestion

Tags: linux, shell

**below is the program**

```
priority="P1"  
if [ $priority=="P3" ]  
then  
    altprt=l5  
elif [ $priority=="P2" ]  
then  
    altprt=l4  
elif [ $priority=="P1" ]  
then  
    altprt=l3  
fi  
echo $altprt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the link describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. Which brings up a good point **What is your question??**

Comment: need spaces between the operators and the operands.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is **Why doesn't this work?** The answer is **(1)** you failed to quote your variables and **(2)** the test constuct `[` is used with a single `=` and **(3)** as Mr. jackmann points out, you need a space surrounding your test construct:

```
priority="P1"  
if [ "$priority" = "P3" ]  
then  
    altprt=l5  
elif [ "$priority" = "P2" ]  
then  
    altprt=l4  
elif [ "$priority" = "P1" ]  
then  
    altprt=l3  
fi  
echo "$altprt"
```

**output:**

```
l3
```

You may also find using `compound expressions` allow for more compact code with the same result:

```
priority="P1"  
[ "$priority" = "P3" ] && altprt=l5
[ "$priority" = "P2" ] && altprt=l4
[ "$priority" = "P1" ] && altprt=l3
echo "$altprt"
```

And finally, you may also use `case` to achieve the same results:

```
priority="P1"  
case "$priority" in
    "P3" ) altprt=l5;;
    "P2" ) altprt=l4;;
    "P1" ) altprt=l3;;
esac
echo "$altprt"
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If it worked, you can 'accept' the answer by clicking 'accept' box at the top-left of the answer. Bash is an amazing shell. You can do in it, just about anything you can do in any high-level programming language. If it needs to be done on a Linux box, you can most likely do it in bash. Spend the time to understand the finer points of string parsing, pattern matching and substring extraction and you will be amazed at what you can do.